# JavaScript library to read data from a WFS server?

Tags: javascript, wfs, api, software-recommendations

Is there a JavaScript library available to read data from a WFS server?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I think OpenLayers is the best. You can easily make WFS calls to an WFS service.

If you want to just return data and not map features, you can also do this. Or map features without the data, or both.

here are some examples:

http://dev.openlayers.org/examples/getfeature-wfs.html

http://dev.openlayers.org/examples/wfs-filter.html

Answer (score 5):

You should be more precise and tell us if you want to use returned data or map features.

See [capdragon answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/7444/115) regarding map features. If you only want to handle data, the following can be a good & light alternative :

If you want to parse a *GetCapabilities* WFS server response, you can just use jQuery because it's xml ( http://marcgrabanski.com/articles/jquery-makes-parsing-xml-easy ). You could also implement jQuery invoking *GetFeature* since output is xml/gml formatted

Comment: Thanks for the reply simo :)  At this point I'm just generically looking into it, so I don't have any specific need for data vs. features. However, keeping it simple and using jQuery to help parse the XML DOM is excellent suggestion.